# How to compress many javascript files in the correct order?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I need to compress a lot of files from one library. But one of them must be loaded first. So I need to do something like this:

```
    {% javascripts
        '@MyBundleBundle/Resources/public/js/foo-file.js'
        '@MyBundleBundle/Resources/public/js/(everything except foo-file).js'
        output='js/all.js'
    %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Twig uses glob() to get the files from the folder specified, therefore if you could list your folder and make a file somehow appear at the top it'll work. The easiest, tbh, that I've found to do this is to rename the "filename.js" as "_filename.js" (note the underscore). Sure, it's a hack, but it works too :)

Comment: @Sarel Thanks but that's only suitable for your own bundles and other libraries installed by composer. If they are third party, you would have to keep your own version of them and it would be a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{% javascripts
    '@MyBundleBundle/Resources/public/js/foo-file.js'
    '@MyBundleBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
    output='js/all.js'
%}
```

It will combine every file in `@MyBundleBundle/Resources/public/js/` directory, being `foo-file.js` the first one.